# Action in MVC Web API controller not firing

Tags: controller, routes, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-1.1

I have an ASP .Net Core 1.1 MVC Web Api. In it, I have a controller that doesn't seem to be working. When I navigate to one of it's actions (it only has one) it doesnt trigger:

```
namespace InspectionsWebApi.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/ValidateUsers")]
    public class ValidateUsersController : Controller
    {
        private readonly InspectionsContext _context;
        private readonly ILogger<UsersController> _logger;

        public ValidateUsersController(InspectionsContext context, ILogger<UsersController> logger)
        {
            _context = context;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        // GET: api/ValidateUsers/abcde12345
        [HttpGet("nameIdentifier")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ValidateUser([FromRoute] string nameIdentifier)
        {
            // This code never fires
        }
    }
}
```

and I navigate to

http://localhost:50082/api/validateusers/john123

I get a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the curly braces to make it a route value:

```
[HttpGet("{nameIdentifier}")]
```

By specifying it without the curly braces, it expects a URL like `http://localhost:50082/api/validateusers/nameIdentifier`.

Comment: Thank you sooo mcuh juunas! That did the trick!I actually thought the curly braces made the parameter optional?